# git Installer didn't update bin path for version 1.7.8.4?

Tags: git

I installed git a long time ago on Snow Leopard... Recently, I downloaded and installed git via git-1.7.8.4-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg installer.

However, when I go to Terminal and type in:

```
git version
```

It responds:

```
git version 1.6.4.2
```

When I do the following:

```
which git
```

It responds:

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

When I cd into that directory and explicitly do the following:

```
./git version
```

Response:

```
git version 1.6.4.2
```

When I go inside:

```
/usr/local/git/bin
```

And run it again explicitly:

```
./git version
```

I am finally able to see this updated version:

```
git version 1.7.8.4
```

How do I change it so from my home directory it will be version 1.7.8.4 ?

Why didn't the installer file do this for me?

Happy programming...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `/usr/local/git/bin` to your `$PATH` before `/usr/local/bin` should help:

**~/.bash_profile**

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: jkbr, thanks! that worked but its still annoying that the installer didn't do it for me.